# HDFS: Canary test failed

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Just installed HDFS using Cloudera Manager. I can access the ameNode WebUI, all nodes are alive. but I get all sorts of

**Canary test failed to create file in directory /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files.**

I tried:

1) `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode get`: it can be confirmed that the namenode is NOT in safe mode. Therefore there should not be any restrict to write operation.

2) `hadoop fs -ls /`: it shows that the `/tmp` directory has full permission 777, which means anyone is supposed to put data into this directory.

By the way, I cannot find anything special in the namenode logs. Why the canary test cannot create file in /tmp???

Answer (score 0):

Check the below directory permission: 
Go to CM >hdfs > Configuration > Monitoring > Service Wide > HDFS Health Canary
Directory Permissions

Answer (score 0):

you can give it a try. Even for some cases I have seen this value set to very high like below:

HDFS Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for hdfs-site.xml

dfs.client.socket-timeout
3000000

dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout
3000000